# How do CloudDeploy FormPage permissions work?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Here’s the [FormPage documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormPage.html) Basic Example:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage["country" -> "Country", GeoGraphics[#country] &]]
```

This creates a CloudObject, but when I try to access it I’m asked to Sign In to the Wolfram Cloud. How do I create a FormPage that does not require a Sign In?

Comment: I just created two cloud objects, one with private and one with public permissions. Pointing my browser to the private one asks for a login, but the public one does not require login. To better keep track of your cloud objects, give them each a different name, for example: `CloudDeploy[FormPage["country"->"Country",GeoGraphics[#country]&],FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory,"FormPageGeoGraphicsPublic"}],Permissions->"Public"]`

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock When I running your code,I get a wrong warning is " *** is not a valid cloud object."

Comment: OK, I can reproduce the problem: If you just copy and past the above code, then unicode 200C "Zero Width Non-Joiner" and unicode 200B "Zero Width Space" characters get included at the line break and cause the error you observed. One way to solve this is by pasting into your previous code just the cloud object name: `FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory,"FormPageGeoGraphicsPublic"}]`

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock Thanks very much,If you give a answer in following,I'll accept it to help the everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sign In to desktop Mathematica before deploying a FormPage to the Wolfram Cloud:

[image: Wolfram Cloud Mathematica Sign In]

By default a FormPage is deployed with Permissions -> "Private". It will be much easier to identify and keep track of CloudObjects if they are named:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage["country" -> "Country", GeoGraphics[#country] &],
   FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "FormPageGeoGraphicsPrivate"}]]
```

Copy web address from CloudObject, paste into your browser, and Sign In:

[image: Wolfram Cloud Firefox Sign In]

The browser will now open to the FormPage as shown in the [FormPage documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormPage.html) Basic Example.

Next deploy a public FormPage:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage["country" -> "Country", GeoGraphics[#country] &],
   FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "FormPageGeoGraphicsPublic"}], 
   Permissions -> "Public"]
```

This FormPage will not require any Sign In. Prove it by signing out on the top right menu of your [Wolfram Development Platform](https://develop.wolframcloud.com/app/) before pasting the public web address into a new browser window.